# Updating a table with another table information using 1 month partition - Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, partitioning

I am having a table A (without partition) which gets overwritten every month. I want to use partition to save this data. What is the best way to achieve this?

My current steps:
Create a new table B with partition every month,
Update table B with table A information.

If my steps are correct, please help to write an optimised query for the same.
My code is given below

```
    CREATE TABLE `A`
    AS
   select
   Col1,
   col2



   create table 'B'
   as
   SELECT
   dt DATE FORMAT 'yyyy-mm-dd',
   Col1 string
   Col2 string
   PARTITION BY RANGE_N(dt BETWEEN DATE '2022-05-23' AND DATE '2028-12-31' EACH INTERVAL '1' MONTH);



  insert into table 'B'
  select
  current_date as dt,
  a.*
  from table A a;
```

Comment: RANGE_N should start on the 1st of a month. Why an outer join instead of a simple Insert/Select from a?

Comment: Also 'partition_date' appears only in the RANGE_N, is this a spelling?

Comment: @justhere yes it's a typo, dt column should have been there. I am editing it. Thanks.

Comment: @dnoeth I am new to SQL, could you explain that?

Comment: Simply `insert into tableB select current_date, tableA.* from tableA;`

Comment: @dnoeth thank you I will edit the code, are the other steps correct? Is there any better syntax to insert data to new partition?

Comment: No, this Ins/Sel is the fastest way.